# How to leak a string in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, string

I was talking to a co-worker the other day about how you can leak a string in Delphi if you really mess things up.  By default strings are reference counted and automatically allocated, so they typically just work without any thought - no need for manual allocation, size calculations, or memory management.

But I remember reading once that there is a way to leak a string directly (without including it in an object that gets leaked).  It seems like it had something to do with passing a string by reference and then accessing it from a larger scope from within the routine it was passed to.  Yeah, I know that is vague, which is why I am asking the question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about the issue in your second paragraph, but I was bitten once by leaked strings in a record.

If you call *FillChar()* on a record that contains strings you overwrite the ref count and the address of the dynamically allocated memory with zeroes. Unless the string is empty this will leak the memory. The way around this is to call *Finalize()* on the record before clearing the memory it occupies.

Unfortunately calling *Finalize()* when there are no record members that need finalizing causes a compiler hint. It happened to me that I commented out the *Finalize()* call to silence the hint, but later when I added a string member to the record I missed uncommenting the call, so a leak was introduced. Luckily I'm generally using the FastMM memory manager in the most verbose and paranoid setting in debug mode, so the leak didn't go unnoticed.

The compiler hint is probably not such a good thing, silently omitting the *Finalize()* call if it's not needed would be much better IMHO.

Comment: > silently omitting the Finalize() call if it's not needed would be much better IMHO
+1

Comment: do you know if short strings affected by this?

Comment: @JamesB: No, short string are not affected by this, as they are not reference counted and don't consist of pointers to chunks of memory that might be lost. Short strings consist of a single length byte and the character data, so filling them with `0`s just sets the length to `0` and sets all elements to `#0`.

Comment: I thought that was the case.... All over our code with have records with short strings (really annoying that data keeps getting truncated because they are not big enough) and I always wondered why... I'll bet this is the reason.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think such a thing can happen. It's possible for a string variable to obtain a value that you didn't expect, but it won't leak memory. Consider this:

```
var
  Global: string;

procedure One(const Arg: string);
begin
  Global := '';

  // Oops. This is an invalid reference now. Arg points to
  // what Global used to refer to, which isn't there anymore.
  writeln(Arg);
end;

procedure Two;
begin
  Global := 'foo';
  UniqueString(Global);
  One(Global);
  Assert(Global = 'foo', 'Uh-oh. The argument isn''t really const?');
end;
```

Here `One`'s argument is declared const, so supposedly, it won't change. But then `One` circumvents that by changing the actual parameter instead of the formal parameter. Procedure `Two` "knows" that `One`'s argument is const, so it expects the actual parameter to retain its original value. The assertion fails.

The string hasn't leaked, but this code does demonstrate how you can get a *dangling reference* for a string. `Arg` is a local alias of `Global`. Although we've changed `Global`, `Arg`'s value remains untouched, and because it was declared const, the string's reference count was not incremented upon entry to the function. Reassigning `Global` dropped the reference count to zero, and the string was destroyed. Declaring `Arg` as var would have the same problem; passing it by value would fix this problem. (The call to `UniqueString` is just to ensure the string is reference-counted. Otherwise, it may be a non-reference-counted string literal.) All compiler-managed types are susceptible to this problem; simple types are immune.

The only way to leak a string is to treat it as something other than a string, or to use non-type-aware memory-management functions. [Mghie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132561/how-to-leak-a-string-in-delphi/1132662#1132662) describes how to treat a string as something other than a string by using `FillChar` to clobber a string variable. Non-type-aware memory functions include `GetMem` and `FreeMem`. For example:

```
type
  PRec = ^TRec;
  TRec = record
    field: string;
  end;

var
  Rec: PRec;
begin
  GetMem(Rec, SizeOf(Rec^));
  // Oops. Rec^ is uninitialized. This assignment isn't safe.
  Rec^.field := IntToStr(4);
  // Even if the assignment were OK, FreeMem would leak the string.
  FreeMem(Rec);
end;
```

There are two ways to fix it. One is to call `Initialize` and `Finalize`:

```
GetMem(Rec, SizeOf(Rec^));
Initialize(Rec^);
Rec^.field := IntToStr(4);
Finalize(Rec^);
FreeMem(Rec);
```

The other is to use type-aware functions:

```
New(Rec);
Rec^.field := IntToStr(4);
Dispose(Rec);
```

Comment: AFAICS the Global example works for any variable type, so it's probably not what Jim is after.

Comment: Ah, you're right. But as a string, it *can* cause additional problems, as I'm about to demonstrate when I edit this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, passing string as CONST or non const are the same in term of reference count in Delphi 2007 and 2009. There was a case that causing access violation when string is passed as CONST. Here is the problem one

```
type
  TFoo = class
    S: string;
    procedure Foo(const S1: string);
  end;

procedure TFoo.Foo(const S1: string);
begin
  S:= S1; //access violation
end;

var
  F: TFoo;
begin
  F:= TFoo.create;
  try
    F.S := 'S';
    F.Foo(F.S);
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: That looks kind of like I was thinking, but it doesn't AV in 2009, which I believe is what you were saying.

Comment: It doesn't AV because in Delphi 2009 the "const" looses its functionality if $STRINGCHECKS are ON.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to leak a string is to declare it as a threadvar variable. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423329) for details. And for the solution, see [the solution on how to tidy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456317/).

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=28) might have been similar to what I was thinking of.  It is the reverse of a string leak, a string that gets collected early:

```
var
  p : ^String;

procedure InitString;
var
  s, x : String;
begin
  s := 'A cool string!';
  x := s + '. Append something to make a copy in' +
             'memory and generate a new string.';

  p := @x;
end;

begin
  { Call a function that will generate a string }
  InitString();

  { Write the value of the string (pointed to by p) }
  WriteLn(p^); // Runtime error 105!


  { Wait for a key press }
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: You have a pointer to an object on the stack that went out of scope.  What do you expect???  Whether or not the string is cleaned up this is likely to blow.

Comment: Loren, you *expect* everything to work exactly as you intended, regardless of the actual code you wrote! The compiler is psychic nowadays, isn't it?

Comment: Gotta agree with Loren here.  The second you invoke the @ symbol, all bets are off.  You're bidding the compiler a polite farewell to any and all type-safety and reference-counting mechanisms and taking the raw memory into your own hands.

Comment: Yeah, this one is pretty obvious.  I'll keep looking, but I may have miss remembered or it got fixed.