# How to define a thread local variable of a generic type in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, thread-safety

I would like to define a thread local variable of the following generic type:

```
type
  TSession<T: TEntity> = class(TInterfacedObject, ISession<T>);
```

I tried to define the variable with the `threadvar` keyword but I am having problems because of the generic parameter:

```
threadvar
   mySession: ISession<T>; // not working
```

What is the recommended way for defining a thread local variable of a generic type in Delphi?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you explain why you can't make do with `threadvar
   mySession: ISession<TConcreteType>;` Thinking about why that doesn't fit your needs will help you work out how to solve the problem, I suspect.

Comment: @David: thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. The answer of has already solved Stefan Glienke my problem.

Comment: So you really do want to have a distinct thread variable for every instantiation of `ISession<T>`? I wonder if you are fully understanding this. That your code now compiles does not imply that it does what you need it to do.

Comment: I want to implement a thread local unit of work, represented by the session object above.

Comment: Why would you need thread local var? What's wrong with passing parameters? By and large we try to avoid thread locals because they are essentially global vars.

Comment: Well of course I could use IoC for this purpose but I got interested in this article by Martin Fowler (in this he uses a java threadlocal construct) and tried to solve it in Delphi. http://thierryroussel.free.fr/java/books/martinfowler/www.martinfowler.com/isa/unitOfWork.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable of an open generic type outside of a generic type (or method), and that has nothing to do with being a `threadvar`.

Either put the `threadvar` inside a generic type (of course it has to be a `class threadvar`) that knows what type of `T` for your `ISession<T>` you are using or use a non generic base type from which `ISession<T>` inherits.

Also you have to know that you may create a memory leak here because threadvars are not implicitly finalized (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456317/how-to-finalise-a-threadvar-string-to-prevent-a-leak)) - you have to take care of that.

Comment: I have tried to put the threadvar inside a generic type but the code does not compile: E2029 'END' expected but 'THREADVAR' found. How do you nest the threadvar inside a generic type?

Comment: You can't nest a threadvar inside a type. A threadvar has global scope, but is instantiated per thread. The first part of the second paragraph of this answer isn't right therefore.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now

Comment: I missed the `class` keyword. This works great, thank you.